# Array not getting sorted properly in my C program

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int n, arr[30],i,j, median, temp; 
    printf("Enter Array Size: "); scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter Array Elements :"); 
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("Array After Sorting: \n");
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
            if(arr[j]<arr[j+1]){   
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
            else{
            continue;
            }
        }
    }
    if (n%2==0){
    median = (arr[n/2]+ arr[n/2+1]/2.0);
    }
    else{
    median = arr[n/2+1];
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    
    printf("Median: %d",median);

}
```

So I'm trying to sort an array and find its median but I'm not getting the expected output

Expected Output:

```
Enter·Array·Size:·4

Enter·Array·Elements·:

5
2
6
1

Array·After·Sorting·:

1
2
5
6

Median:·3
```

Output that I'm getting:

```
Enter·Array·Size:·4

Enter·Array·Elements·:

5
2
6
1
    
Array·After·Sorting:·
6
5
2
1

Median:·2
```

This is my C programming lab question and they haven't taught us a thing about sorting but they want us to solve all this stuff.

I can't seem to understand what's wrong with the code.

**Edit:**

@Harry Ramsay's fix worked for the sorting algorithm.

However I seem to have issues with the median.

@Faith Furkan Cambel's fix worked for only one test case.

There's another test case:

```
Enter·Array·Size:·3

Enter·Array·Elements·:

5
9
2

Array·After·Sorting·:

2

5

9

Median:·5
```

I'm getting the median of second test case as 9 instead of 5

Comment: You are sorting it correctly, your comparison is just the wrong way around. If you want it in increasing order, your if statement should be `if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])`.

Comment: `if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1])` I'm pretty sure this condition should be reversed, otherwise, you're swapping values that are already in ascending order

Comment: One issue with the median calculation is it looks like it's intended for 1-indexed arrays, not 0-indexed ones like C uses. (For a 4 element array you want indexes 1 and 2. What ones are you calculating?)

Comment: That seemed to fix the sorting issue but now I'm having issues with the median

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the calculation of the median. Change this line:

```c
median = (arr[n/2] + arr[n/2 + 1]) / 2.0;
```

to:

```c
median = (arr[n/2 - 1] + arr[n/2]) / 2;
```

Comment: That fixed the first test case but the second test case is failing now. I'll update the question with the second test case